# Migration of core banking application from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, migration

The following tasks were considered for value upgrade to Windows Server 2008. 
However, the later decision is just to go with platform upgrade from windows server 2003 to windows server 2008 32 Bit

1. Analyze the prerequiesites before installing windows server 2008
2. Identify dependent programs and their implementation aspects & prepare a document
3. List down breaking changes in windows server 2008
4. Prepare Run Environment upgrade requirements
5. Run regression test, volume and performance test

I need details on which of those steps are relevant for a plain platform upgrade from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2008

Comment: There is not windows 2008 32bit. The only 32bit versions of 2k8 are for testing.

Comment: @t1nt1n that is factually incorrect. 2008R2 is the first OS with no 32bit versions, 2008 still ship in 32bit versions

Answer (score 1):

Given the little information you've provided, I'd say that all steps are relevants. If you need more details, you'll need to provide (a lot) more details yourself